# auto renew with price set for 2 memberships to 2 different organisations

Tags: civimember, auto-renew

I am trying to create a contribution page with two memberships of different time periods that both require autorenewal. I have tried this (both memberships that are referenced by the price set have auto renewal required enacted) and each one of those membership goes to a seperate organisation so that clicking both memberships is possible without just updating one with the other.
But testing it (with 1 day renewal and 2 renewal for the other one), i don't see the notice that it is recurring payments and striple also only takes the first round of payments.

I'm using WordPress 5.1.1 and CiviCRM 5.13.1.

Any help would be really appreciated,
best regards,
David

Comment: if there is only one transaction being passed to Stripe then I don't see how having different cycles would be possible without some customisation that would cause more than one set of data to be fired off at Stripe